# For Which images Haar_cascade_frontolface classifier are trainend in opencv

Tags: android, opencv, haar-classifier, haar-wavelet

I am using the Haar cascade classifier in android and using the XML files.
But I want to know that these already trained classifier are trained for which images and where i can find them ??

Answer (score 0):

The similar question on [answers.opencv](http://answers.opencv.org/question/29836/details-of-dataset-used-for-training-face-haarcascades/) refers to [this](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) post, where is mentioned (but not *confirmed*) that OpenCV developers used the [FERET](http://www.itl.nist.gov/iad/humanid/feret/feret_master.html) dataset.

---

But you don't need to know this in the first place. Or you are ok with pre-trained data, or you train your own.

You can find other dataset that can be useful to train your own classifier [here](http://www.cvpapers.com/datasets.html) and [here](http://www.computervisiononline.com/datasets).

Comment: I just want to know that where actually data is placed for which classifiers are trained. Did these XML files(placed in raw folder) have links with the Images   ???

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you mean

Comment: I am using OCV Face detection sample. and want to know how these classifiers are working??? On which images these are trained and did these have any links with the images ???

Comment: _How these classifiers are working?_ Read about _cascade classifiers_. _On which images are trained?_ Probably on FERET. _Did this have any links with the images_? Well, probably to train a face detection classifiers they used images of faces.. :D